# Cancancan - define :create with association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan

I have the following situation in my Ruby on Rails application:

I have a blog with posts. Each post can have 1 to *n* authors, and each post is associated with several comments:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :authors

class Comment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :post
```

I am using CanCanCan for authorization. Currently everyone is able to create comments on a post. I want to change this by introducing a `lock_comments`-attribute on my `post` model, and changing the authorization accordingly, so that it functions as follows:

- If the user is not logged in, allow comment `:create` if `lock_comments` on it's parent post is false
- If the user is logged in, allow comment `:create` if `lock_comments` on it's parent post is false, OR the logged in user is one of the authors of the post

Basically the authors should be able to disable comments on their articles, but they should still be able to write comments on their own articles, even if the comments are disabled for others.

I am a bit at a loss here and could not find anything in the documentation. How do I have to define my `Ability` for this to work?

Comment: Hi Sirius! Maybe you can show us a little bit more of your code and how you're trying to solve the problem. Its certainly will make it easier to for us to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do this in Ability because at the time you're trying to access `create` you don't know what the parent post is. You COULD do this if `create_comment` was a `PostsController` method...

```
can :create_comment, Post do |post|
  !post.lock_comments || user.in?(post.authors)
end
```

But if it's `create` in a `CommentsController` you'd need to do this with a `before_action`

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :create_allowed, only: [:create]

  private

  def create_allowed
    post = Post.find(params[:comment][:post_id])
    return if post && (!post.lock_comments || current_user.in?(post.authors))
    flash[:error] = 'You are not allowed to do this'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```